# Localisation of Video

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I am developing an application which contains a video on the home screen. The video will be different for different region. Because the size of a single video is 10 Mb and I have almost 10 videos for different country. So I don't want to store those locally. So my questions are :

1. Should google play developer console provide the way where I can store those video separately from My apk file and at time of download, corresponding region video downloaded from there and I can link that video to my application.
2. What will be the better way to achieve that functionality? I want to reduce loading time which require to download the video from web server.
   Thanks in advance.